# How do I access User Model field in the Serializer of extended User Model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-knox

I am creating a simple registration/login app in Django Rest Framework using Rest APIs with Django Rest Knox's authentication, in which, upon registration, user will also upload a CSV File (which is an optional field).

I have a `Person` Model which is an extended (derived or `OneToOne`) Model of `User` Model and has `FileField` for the file to be uploaded.

I have two `ModelSerializer`s, one is based on `User` Model named `MainRegisterSerializer` and serializes `username`, `email` and `password` fields, and the other is based on `Person` Model named `RegisterSerializer`, which serializes `FileField` and `register` field (that is initialized with `MainRegisterSerializer` class's constructor.

Now, in `views.py`, I am accessing the `RegisterSerializer`, to get the data from front that which includes `username`, `email` and `password` fields from `User` Model, and `FileField` from `Person` Model.

But, when I enter data in front-end and upload the file, and click on `POST` button, I get the following error:

```
KeyError at /api/v1/register
'username'
```

on the code line `user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'], validated_data['file'])` in `serializers.py` file.

My **`views.py`** is:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer


class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        return Response({
            "users": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": token[1]
        })
```

My **`serializers.py`** is:

```
from .models import Person
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class MainRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    register = MainRegisterSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['register', 'file',]
        optional_fields = ['file',]
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'], validated_data['file'])
        return user
```

My **`models.py`** is:

```
from django.db import models.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="CSV File")
```

I have already worked around by trying various solutions told here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me, that's why I am posting the question. Any help will surely be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to include `username` in `RegisterSerializer`'s fields. Hence, the key error is raised when trying to access `username` key in `validated_data`.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't import `User` model directly. You should call `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` function to get `User` model. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: @annonymous I want to access the `username` field of `MainRegisterSerializer` in `RegisterSerializer`, I don't want to create a separate `username` field in `RegisterSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the validated data you can see, the data belonging to `MainRegisterSerializer` serializer will be available with `register` key. And data belonging to `RegisterSerializer` serializer will be available with `file` key.

**validated data :**

```
{'register': OrderedDict([('username', 'test'), ('email', 'test@gmail.com'), ('password', 'test123')]), 'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: filename.txt (text/csv)>}
```

so to access any fields for register you need to use:

```
validated_data['register']['username'], validated_data['register']['email'] ..etc.
```

for accessing the file you can use : `validated_data['file']`